# ExtJs Grid - Error on setSize if cellediting active

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

My gridpanel has a store and uses the cellediting plugin.

When I reload my grid via `loadData()`, I also `reconfigure()` my grid's columns and call my model's `setFields()`.

So while this is happening, click a editable grid cell in this gird by simple clicking it, and then an error gets thrown:

Code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setSize' of undefined Editor.js:48
Ext.define.calculate Editor.js:48
Ext.define.runLayout Context.js:1154
Ext.define.runCycle Context.js:1123
Ext.define.run Context.js:1054
Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts AbstractComponent.js:84
Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts AbstractComponent.js:100
Ext.resumeLayouts AbstractComponent.js:3437
Ext.define.reconfigure Table.js:1024
...
```

I tried preventing it by completing the edit process with:

Code:

```
if ( oView.editingPlugin ) 
     {
        oView.editingPlugin.completeEdit();
     }
```

but this fails.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Can you isolate your grid in a separate component by extending the standard grid and adding your config and methods?
If you can post that here, it would be very useful. It could be tested separately to confirm it is not related to the config.

Comment: Thanks. I have separated the grid. Is that enough or should I add more code? http://jsfiddle.net/H8zUv/

Comment: It would be really good if you could make this work. Meaning: a dummy `oStore`, include Deft JS (from github for instance) and find a solution for that one Netmind controller which is referenced.
That way we would have a perfect test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with calling my records to `.commit()` and my editingPlugin to `.completeEdit()`. This stops the editing process.